# Animate Canvas Fill() from bottom to top using JavaScript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

I am working on the demo code below. How can I add animation to Canvas `Fill()` from bottom to top using JavaScript or jQuery?

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.rect(20, 20, 150, 100);
ctx.fillStyle = "red";


setInterval(function(){ctx.fill() }, 3000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="150" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>
```

Comment: Well, simulating slow computers of ancient eras clearly wasn't intention of HTML canvas spec designers. You most probably will have to implement your own fill algorithm then. With some luck it's performing poorly enough to get the desired effect implicitly. ;) Aside from that if all you need is a rectangle growing in height from bottom to top try to work w/o canvas but with div element and some CSS transition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know a proper way to do that without algorithm.

I made this algorithm which does what you want, i hope it will help you.

Tested on google chrome, you can play with thick and timeout parameter.

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="150" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>
<script>

var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

//Configuration
var myRect = {"x":20,"y":20,"w":150,"h":100}  //rect definition
timeInterval= 250;          //time between 2 draw
thick = 3;             //thickness of a line (pixel)
ctx.fillStyle = "red";  //color of the rect

var cpt = 0;

//loop will process fast but we make a delay on each draw with setTimeout which grow at each iteration
for(var ind = thick; ind < myRect.h+thick ; ind += thick){
  setTimeout(function(ind){
      drawLittleRect(ind)
  }, timeInterval*cpt, ind);
  cpt++
}

function drawLittleRect(ind){
  var tempY = myRect.y + myRect.h - ind;

  //Limit top of rect in order to get desired size
  if(tempY < myRect.y){
    tempY = myRect.y
  }
  ctx.fillRect(myRect.x, tempY,  myRect.w, thick);
}
</script>
```